# Modify an infopath repeating field to replace spaces in a URL

Tags: url, field, infopath, concatenation, repeat

SharePoint 2010

I have a repeating section that displays an URL on an infopath form built from a list.
Currently it displays URL with the spaces in it. I want to replace those spaces with a %20 to make them link correctly.

Below is the rule I added onto the section. It does replace the spaces with %20 correctly

Runs when field changes
myURL = concat(substring-before(myURL, " "), "%20", substring-after(myURL, " "))

HOWEVER, when multiple links are to be displayed, it replaces all of the URLs with the same exact URL.
e.g.
Incoming data:
Link one
Link two
Link three

What I expect (I want this):
Link%20one
Link%20two
Link%20three

What I get (Don't want):
Link%20three
Link%20three
Link%20three

How do I keep the links as individuals and not get overwritten?

- dataFields

  - ListItem          << Rule above is here

    - ID
    - Attachments

      - myURL

The repeating field is the myURL.

Again, the infopath form is based form a list therefore the developer tab isn't available.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the function should go in the XPath for the Hyperlink object. I didn't realize you could put functions inside the XPath.

In the end here is what I did:

- removed the rule I had created
- put the function concat(substring-before(myURL, " "), "%20", substring-after(myURL, " ")) in the XPath of the hyperlink object
- Publish and celebrate

Thanks to Sergio Giusti over on Technet for leading me down the right path (pun intended).